# Records created with FactoryGirl not available in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot

One of my tests has started failing.  It previously worked and going through the same actions by hand in the browser show the feature to be working.

I create the records to be tested like this:

```
will = FactoryGirl.create(:user, profile: "security of the internet", first_name: "will")
```

To investigate, I added a

```
binding.pry
```

call in my controller.  The action searches Users.

If i do:

```
User.all
```

at the pry prompt, no users are shown, an empty result.

If i break into the actual test with pry, User.all shows the expected records.

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is because your test is tagged js: true and is using a JS capable driver but you are using transactional database testing.  When using the "full browser" drivers the app and tests run.  Different threads so they each have their own database connection.  This means objects created in one threads transaction aren't visible in the other until committed, but when using transaction based testing nothing ever gets committed. To fix, turn off transactional testing and use truncation or deletion for that test - see database_cleaner

Comment: My test isn't marked as js: true and i already have database_cleaner set up to use truncation

Comment: @Will  Add your database cleaner and Capybara configs to the question please

Comment: Using database_cleaner with truncation doesn't mean you aren't using running the tests in a transaction.  They usually would go together, but configuring one won't automatically configure the other.  Search your code for `use_transactional_fixtures` to see if you're doing anything unusual with that setting.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh - thank you.  i had this line:   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true  set in rails_helper.rb.  I don't understand why that suddenly became a problem.  It seems to have been linked to tests that used the devise signin methods.  anyway, setting that to false gives me a passing set of tests.  thank you.

Comment: Did you recently update any of the gems in your Gemfile?  Which ones?  That might help us figure out why things changed.

Comment: @Will If you use the database_cleaner recommended config from https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example it actually warns you about the setting if it's ever set wrong

Comment: sorry, my mistake it has not fixed the issue.

Comment: when i saved the rails_helper a bunch of tests ran because guard saw that the helper had changed, i saw all the green lights and thought it was fixed, but the test i'm trying to fix is still failing

Comment: i also facing this issue at my end if any one get  solution please share. Thanks